# Get Dynamic Values in app.module.ts for Angular Application

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, cookies, angular-social-login

I'm using the `angularx-social-login` package for social login purposes in my application. As per the documentation, I've to pass the google and Facebook client id within `app.module.ts`. But that's where my problem starts because I need to keep that dynamic and fetch the id's from cookies instead of passing the client id as a static string. To make it dynamic I tried to make a service and also export a function in `app.module` but nothing seems to work. When making an export function I can't pass cookies within it since there is no constructor to initialize the cookies and when passing the function through a service I cannot exclusively call it in app.module since I need to first create an instance of the service to call the service methods. Have been stuck with it for days now. Any sort of idea will be appreciated.

**app.module.ts**

```
 let config = new AuthServiceConfig([
  {
    id: GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    provider: new GoogleLoginProvider("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")  //need to make this dynamic
  },
  {
    id: FacebookLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    provider: new FacebookLoginProvider("xxxxxxxxxx") //need to make this dynamic
  }
]);
  
export function provideConfig() {
  return config;
}
```

service to fetch dynamic data

```
import { Injectable,Inject} from '@angular/core';
import { SocialLoginModule, AuthServiceConfig } from "angularx-social-login";
import { GoogleLoginProvider, FacebookLoginProvider } from "angularx-social-login";
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AppSocialLoginService { 

    public google;
    public facebook;
    public tempCookie;

    constructor(private _cookiesService:CookieService) { 
        this.tempCookie = this._cookiesService.getObject('globalData');
     }

     getGoogle() {
        if (this.tempCookie && this.tempCookie.hasOwnProperty('google_login_client_id')) {
            this.google = this.tempCookie['google_login_client_id'];
            return this.google;
          }
     }

     getFacebook() {
        if (this.tempCookie && this.tempCookie.hasOwnProperty('fb_login_id')) {
            this.facebook = this.tempCookie['fb_login_id'];
            return this.facebook;
          }
    }

     provideConfig() {
        let config = new AuthServiceConfig([
            {
              id: GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
              provider: new GoogleLoginProvider(this.getGoogle())
            },
            {
              id: FacebookLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
              provider: new FacebookLoginProvider(this.getFacebook())
            }
          ]);
    
          return config;
     } // cannot export this function in app.module since it's already in a class

 }
```

Tried to make a function and export it to app.module but then the problem is I cannot initialize a constructor and get the cookies to pass inside the function

```
    export function provideConfig() {
    let config = new AuthServiceConfig([
        {
          id: GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
          provider: new GoogleLoginProvider("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx") //can't receive cookies in this
        },
        {
          id: FacebookLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
          provider: new FacebookLoginProvider("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx") //can't receive cookies in this
        }
      ]);

      return config;
 }
```

Comment: You need to use a factory provider.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit?